Scalar function differentiation w.r.t. a vector and vector integration
I want to prove the following equality by going both ways, by integrating and taking the derivative on the right-hand side directly. Incidentally, this comes from an astrophysics boook.
$$ \ddot{\mathbf{r}_j} = - \frac{\partial \Phi_j( \mathbf{r_j},t)}{\partial \mathbf{r}_j}$$
where:
$$\ddot{\mathbf{r}_j} = \sum_{k=0,k \neq j}^{N-1} \frac{ \mathbb{G} m_k (\mathbf{r}_k - \mathbf{r}_j)}{|\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r}_k|^3} , \hspace{1cm} \Phi_j( \mathbf{r_j},t) = - \sum_{k=0,k \neq j}^{N-1} \frac{ \mathbb{G} m_k}{|\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r_k}(t)|}$$
for $ j = 0, ... , N-1$.
I first tried integrating the left-hand side to see if it matched the right-hand side:
$$ - \int \ddot{\mathbf{r}_j} \cdot d\mathbf{r}_i =  \int  \frac{\partial \Phi_j( \mathbf{r_j},t)}{\partial \mathbf{r}_j} \cdot d \mathbf{r}_i$$
$$ - \int \sum_{k=0,k \neq j}^{N-1} \frac{ \mathbb{G} m_k (\mathbf{r}_k - \mathbf{r}_j)}{|\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r}_k|^3} \cdot d\mathbf{r}_i = \int \Phi_j(\mathbf{r}_j,t) \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_i}{\partial \mathbf{r}_j}}_{ \delta( \mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_j)}$$
$$ - \int \sum_{k=0,k \neq j}^{N-1} \frac{ \mathbb{G} m_k (\mathbf{r}_k - \mathbf{r}_j)}{|\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r}_k|^3} \cdot d\mathbf{r}_i = \Phi_j(\mathbf{r}_j,t) $$
I also assumed absolute convergence to switch the sum with the integral:
$$ - \sum_{k=0,k \neq j}^{N-1} \mathbb{G} m_k \int \frac{(\mathbf{r}_k - \mathbf{r}_j)}{|\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r}_k|^3} \cdot d\mathbf{r}_i = \Phi_j(\mathbf{r}_j,t)$$
$$  \sum_{k=0,k \neq j}^{N-1} \mathbb{G} m_k \int \frac{ \mathbf{\hat{r}}}{|\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r}_k|^2} \cdot d\mathbf{r}_i = \Phi_j(\mathbf{r}_j,t)$$
$$  \sum_{k=0,k \neq j}^{N-1}  \mathbb{G} m_k  \frac{ 1}{|\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r}_k|}  = \Phi_j(\mathbf{r}_j,t)$$
where:
$$  \mathbf{\hat{r}} := \frac{(\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r}_k)}{|\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r}_k|}  $$
the hat denotes a unit vector. I took this simplified approach to show what I did but I have some confusion in regards to showing all the necessary steps.
How do I complete this integration process pedantically on the left-hand side? Does a negative sign come from the dot product between the unit vector and the differential element?

The first equation in OP is the Euler-Lagrange equation for a system with time dependent potential $\Phi,.$ Please study some basic Hamiltonian mechanics. I'd assume that a decent Astrophysics book mentions that in one of the first chapters.
